# Documents needed to cross the border into Canada and back into the USA

Tags: paperwork, canadian-citizens, us-permanent-residents

Do I need a passport to cross into Canada if I am a born citizen of Canada but I am a permanent resident of the USA with a green card?

Comment: Are you traveling by land or by air?

Comment: The [most highly upvoted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/120741/19400) at this point is incorrect because it leads to the conclusion that a green card is not sufficient, but in fact a green card is sufficient.

Comment: As of April 26, 2022, a green card is no longer useful for a Canadian citizen entering Canada, but a passport is still not required.  See [my answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/120761/19400) for details.

Answer (score 7):

If you're flying, you'll need a valid passport or NEXUS card.  For trips by land, [as of April 26, 2022, US permanent residents are no longer able to enter Canada using only a green card](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=593&top=16).  (See the edit history for a description of the requirements before that date.)  Therefore, you will have to rely on the ability of Canadian citizens to prove their citizenship and identity using means other than a passport.  The listed documents do not include the green card, however, nor US driver's licenses.  I suspect that this is an oversight, but to be safe in case it isn't, you'll want to select from the documents on the list.  Your proof of citizenship could be, for example, your birth certificate or a citizenship certificate, while proof of identity could be a credit card or a social insurance number card.  The complete lists are below:

From [Travel documents and identification requirements](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html):

> **Acceptable documents to denote identity and citizenship**
>
> Upon arrival at a Canadian port of entry, travellers must satisfy a CBSA border services officer (BSO) that they meet the requirements for entry into Canada. For Canadian citizens, permanent residents and persons registered under the Indian Act, this can be done through questioning and through verifying documentation such as a:
>
> - Canadian passport
> - Canadian birth certificate
> - Permanent residence card
> - citizenship card
> - Secure Certificate of Indian Status (SCIS) card or valid Certificate of Indian Status (CIS) card
>
> If you do not have a passport, and are returning to Canada, the following documents can denote identity and citizenship:
>
> - NEXUS card, held by a Canadian citizen, when entering Canada by air (when coming from the U.S.), land, or marine modes
> - FAST card (Free and Secure Trade), issued to a Canadian citizen (when arriving by land or marine modes only)
> - Canadian emergency travel document
> - Canadian temporary passport
> - Certificate of Canadian citizenship (issued from 1954 to present)
> - Enhanced driver's license issued by a Canadian province or territory
> - Enhanced identification/photo card issued by a Canadian province or territory
>
> **Other acceptable documents for establishing Canadian citizenship**
>
> The following documents may be used to establish Canadian citizenship. Upon presentation by travellers, the documents should be supported by other government issued photo identification:
>
> - Certificate of Canadian citizenship (large form issued between January 1, 1947, to February 14, 1977)
> - Certificate of retention (issued between January 1, 1947, and February 14, 1977)
> - Certificate of naturalization (issued before January 1, 1947)
> - Registration of birth abroad certificate (issued between January 1, 1947, and February 14, 1977, by Canadian citizenship authorities)
> - Provincial or territorial birth certificate (individuals born in Canada
>
> **Other acceptable documents to support identity**
>
> The following documents may be used to establish your identity:
>
> - CANPASS card (air, corporate air, private air, remote area border crossing), held by a Canadian citizen
> - Commercial driver registration program card, held by a Canadian citizen
> - Provincial and territorial driver's license
> - Employment or student card with photo and signature
> - Provincial health insurance card
> - Provincial identity card
> - Canadian Forces identification
> - Police identification
> - Firearms acquisition certificate
> - Social insurance number card
> - Credit card
> - Vehicle insurance certificate
> - Vehicle registration
>
> **Acceptable documents for establishing Registered Indian Status and identity**
>
> Every person registered under the Indian Act can enter and remain in Canada by right as per subsection A19(1) of the Immigration and Refugee Protection Act. The Secure Certificate of Indian Status (SCIS), more commonly referred to as the Status card, is an identity document issued by Indian and Northern Affairs Canada confirming that the cardholder is registered as a Status Indian under the Indian Act.
>
> Note: The Certificate of Indian Status (CIS) was replaced by the SCIS in 2009. Existing versions of the CIS will remain valid until their renewal date.

As to reentering the US by land, a green card is sufficient:

> What documents do I need to present to reenter the United States?

> If seeking to enter the United States after temporary travel abroad, you will need to present a valid, unexpired “green card” (Form I-551, Permanent Resident Card). When arriving at a port of entry, a U.S. Customs and Border Protection Officer will review your permanent resident card and any other identity documents you present, such as a passport, foreign national I.D. card or U.S. Driver’s License, and determine if you can enter the United States.  For information pertaining to entry into the United States, see [U.S. Customs and Border Protection’s webpage](http://www.cbp.gov/).

The lack of a passport requirement for green card holders is found at [8 CFR 211.2(a)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/211.2#a_2):

> § 211.2 Passports.
>
> (a) A passport valid for the bearer's entry into a foreign country at least 60 days beyond the expiration date of his or her immigrant visa shall be presented by each immigrant except an immigrant who:
>
> ...
>
> (2) Is entering under the provisions of § 211.1(a)(2) through (a)(7);

Where [8 CFR 211.1(a)(2)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/211.1#a_2) reads:

> § 211.1 Visas.
>
> (a) General. Except as provided in paragraph (b)(1) of this section, each arriving alien applying for admission (or boarding the vessel or aircraft on which he or she arrives) into the United States for lawful permanent residence, or as a lawful permanent resident returning to an unrelinquished lawful permanent residence in the United States, shall present one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> (2) A valid, unexpired Form I-551, Permanent Resident Card, if seeking readmission after a temporary absence of less than 1 year, ...

Comment: @JonathanReez you missed the comments where it was pointed out to me that Canada changed the rules last month.  I'll put the link to the relevant page back into this version of the answer.

Comment: You're right. I literally entered Canada on just a Green Card on April 26th though, I guess the border guard was lenient.

Comment: @JonathanReez your experience certainly reinforces my suspicion that the cited document was written without considering Canadian citizens who live in the US.  I can't imagine that they wouldn't accept a US green card as proof of identity, and if they were willing to give you a day's lenience on the rule change, it's surely possible that they'd accept it as evidence of the place of birth (and therefore citizenship).

Comment: I'll go to Canada again in June and see if they actually ask to see my passport when I give them my Green Card.

Comment: Entered Canada this week and the border guard only wanted to see my Green Card. I purposefully kept my passport in the glove compartment and it wasn't brought up at all. So either the guidance is wrong or the border guards just don't care to enforce it.

Answer (score 2):

To cross into Canada you'll need:

- for land, water, or air travel, a passport, or
- if crossing by land or water, a US passport card (unless you're also a US citizen, you won't be eligible for one), or
- if crossing by land or water, an enhanced driver's license (only a few states provide these, usually at extra cost) (only available to US citizens), or
- for air, water or land travel, a NEXUS trusted traveler card (Canpass will work as well, but this isn't valid for returning to the US)

If the border officer is satisfied with your claim of citizenship, it is possible you will be admitted without these documents, but you're taking a big chance as you may be turned back.

[Here is Canada's web page on entry requirements for US citizens and permanent residents.](http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html)

Comment: A US green card should be enough to enter Canada by land without any of those documents you listed

Comment: @user102008 It's *probably* enough, but it doesn't meet the technical requirements.  The US certainly gives us Canadians grief if we try to cross without one of these pieces of ID, although we are often let in anyway.

Comment: OP cannot get an enhanced driver's license because only US citizens are eligible to get them in the US.  Also, unless something has changed recently, Canada accepts green cards by themselves for entry by land, and so does the US.

Comment: @phoog I included it to be comprehensive, and on the off chance that the question asker is a dual citizen.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie the asker could not be a dual citizen and also "a permanent resident of the USA with a green card"

Comment: "It's probably enough, but it doesn't meet the technical requirements": it absolutely meets the technical requirements.  See my answer.

Comment: @phoog http://www.cbsa.gc.ca/travel-voyage/td-dv-eng.html The use of a passport is strongly encouraged, according to this.  Whether any other identification is acceptable is entirely at the discretion of the border officer.  The question discusses only entering Canada, so I've focused my answer on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81828/discussion-between-phoog-and-jim-mackenzie).

Comment: The current CBSA page makes it clear that proof of citizenship such as a Canadian birth certificate and proof of identity such as a social insurance number card are sufficient.  Even though the green card is no longer sufficient, or even necessary, a Canadian passport is also not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your travel plan. The exact rules (air, land, sea) are spelled out here https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/619/~/visiting-the-u.s.---documents-required-for-canadian-citizens-%2F-residents-%2F

In addition to the "formal" rules, US immigration officers have a fair bit of "discretion" so there can be some significant variability there as well.

The easiest and obvious answer: get a passport. It's not that hard or expensive and makes travel quite a bit safer and easier.

Comment: US immigration officers do not need "discretion" to admit a green card holder with only a green card; by either statute or regulation (I have forgotten which), that is sufficient documentation.

Comment: Furthermore, the page you link to concerns *visitors* to the US who are citizens, residents, or landed immigrants of Canada.  It does not apply to green card holders.